# quasar framework - colour and font size of stacked label

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the latest quasar framework. I want to change the colour and font size of the stacked label in a q-input field.
Changing the in the css doesn’t seem to take effect. Any local styling apply only to the input text and not to the label.
how to solve this problem?
Thanks,
Priy

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: <q-input v-model="timescale" stack-label="Timescale:" @change="timescaleChanged"/>